# jQuery li hover complete code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul id='ulid'>
<li>Task1</li>
<li>Task2</li>
<li>Task3</li>
<li>Task4</li>
<li>Task5</li>
<li>Task6</li>
<li>Task7</li>
</ul>
<div id="show_details"></div>
```

I would like what's the JavaScript that I can use to copy the details of the `li` into the `div` on `mouseover` hide it on `mouseout`.

Comment: What do you mean by "details"!? Because if there is, I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for a particular ul:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

 $('ul#ulid li').hover(function() {
    $('#show_details').html( $(this).text() );
  }, function() {
    $('#show_details').html( '' );
 });

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ynPJR/)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the "content" with "details", you might want to try:

```
var $details = $('#show_details');
$('ul > li').hover(function(){
   $details.text($(this).text());
}, function(){
   $details.text('');
});
```

Ref.: [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: Hi jAndy, thanks for the code, but there are more than one ul elements are there, And I want to get the details from a particular ul, please elaborate how can I proceed for that. thanks

Comment: @dave: to only execute the code on a particular `ul`, you need an unique identifier which should be created via the `ID` tag. So you HTML code should look like `<ul id="mylist">` which can be queried by `$('#mylist')`.

Comment: Hi jAndy, can you give me the exact code, because i m not able to get the desired results. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Ref** :  **[jQuery.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** , **[jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** , **[jQuery.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/)**

```
$(function() {
 $('li').hover(function() {
    $('#show_details').html( $(this).text() );
  }, function() {
    $('#show_details').empty()
 });
});
```

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks for the code, but there are more than one ul elements are there, And  I want to get the details from a particular ul, please elaborate how can I proceed for that. thanks

Comment: Dave, Just Give a Reference like an id or class (`selectors` : http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors ) to your target Element & pass the reference Element as the selector to jQuery as parameter !